# Laravel error variable

Tags: php, laravel

How can I forward the custom value to error variable if a condition is met? I am doing a validation on user creation, and everything works except when I use the existing e-mail (which is unique in DB), which then crashes the app.

It would be great if that could be done in `CreateUserRequest` but I found no such thing, so I am filtering it out in controller.

Returning JSON worked like so:

```
public function store(CreateUserRequest $request)
{
    if (User::whereEmail($request['email'])->first()) {
       return Response::json([
                'error' => 'User with given e-mail already exists',
            ], 409);
    else {
        $user = User::create($request->all());
        return redirect('user');
        }
}
```

But in my view I have:

```
@if ($errors->has('email'))
<span class="help-block" style="color: red">
    <strong>
    {{ $errors->first('email') }}
    </strong>
</span>
@endif
```

So I was wondering if there is a way to forward a message from my controller to global `$error` variable?

Comment: You can add in rules method in CreateUserRequest, 'email' => 'required|unique'. It will not post the request to controller until this rule is validated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['email', 'The Message']);
```

but better approch would be to check this in `CreateUserRequest` validation.

```
// rules
'email' => 'required|unique:users',
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like that:

```
public function store(CreateUserRequest $request){

    if (User::whereEmail($request->email)->exists()) 
       return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['email' => 'User with given e-mail already exists']);

    $user = User::create($request->all());
    return redirect('user');

}
```